# How do I create users in the Cassandra shell?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I'm new to Cassandra and trying to deploy an application using Cassandra. I created a keyspace in my Cassandra DB but when I create my keyspace account I get an error like below

I have tried many ways like create user and create roles but it doesn't work. The version I am using is 3.11.13

```
CREATE ROLE etl WITH PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx' AND LOGIN = true;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
message="org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager doesn't support PASSWORD"
```

```
CREATE ROLE
CREATE USER
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you haven't enabled authentication in your cluster.

The `PASSWORD` option is only supported if you have configured `PasswordAuthenticator`. By default, authentication is disabled in `cassandra.yaml` with:

```
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
```

You need to configure the nodes with the password authenticator to enable authentication:

```
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
```

For details, see [Enabling Password Authentication in Cassandra 3.11](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/operating/security.html#password-authentication). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to your guidance I have created a user